# dividing all haskell array values with their gcd

Tags: haskell

I have the following code

```
reducer :: Row El -> Row El
reducer r = let getGCD l = map (\x y -> gcd x y) l
                gcd' = getGCD r
                f = (\x -> map (\y -> y * gcd') x)
             in (f (r))
```

in order to divide an array with its gcd.

```
reducer [8,8,12] :: Row Int
-- > [2,2,3]
```

but I couldn't manage to fit to `reducer :: Row El -> Row El` function type, so basically code doesn't work.

How can I fix it?

Comment: `map` expects a function of type `a -> b`; you are providing one of type `a -> b -> c`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GCD of 3 or more numbers must be computed taking *all* numbers into account. The simplest way to do this is to compute the GCD of the tail of the list recursively, then compute the GCD of that value and the head. Since `gcd x 0 == x` for any x, we can define the base case to be 0. (Haskell's implementation of `gcd` also defines `gcd 0 0 == 0`.)

```
getGCD [] = 0
getGCD (x:rest) = gcd x (getGCD rest)
```

Once you have that, you can find the GCD of your list, then *divide* each number by the GCD.

```
reducer r = let gcd' = getGCD r
            in map (\x -> div x gcd') r
```

Comment: what does not work? - the calculation of the gcd - or the reducer and in which way - does not compile or produces unexpected output - I think @chepner might have omitted one case `getGCD [x] = x`.

Answer (score 3):

GCD of multiple numbers:

```
gcd' = foldl gcd 0 :: (Integral b, Foldable t) => t b -> b
```

Which you can then use to divide all numbers in the array:

```
div' xs = map (`div` g) xs
  where
    g = gcd' xs
```